# Change default class for sorted columns in a jquery Datatable?

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I'm trying to change the default class assigned to the  elements that are in the sorted column. According to the [Datatable documentation](http://legacy.datatables.net/styling/custom_classes) the property is "sSortColumn"  (Default is "sorting_").

The docs state that an index is appended to the class name. (sorting_n)

I have the following datatable defined:

```
    oTable = $("#user-table").dataTable({
            "sAjaxSource": "/users",
            "bServerSide": true,
            "bProcessing": true,
            "sSortColumn": "foobar",
            "aoColumns": [null, null, null, {"bSortable": false}],
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "bAutoWidth": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "bPaginate": true
        });
```

When I inspect a TD in the sorted column the class is still the default:

```
    <td class="sorting_1">user1207</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On that [page you linked to](http://legacy.datatables.net/styling/custom_classes) - it tells how you can set the default classes

```
Two different sets of default classes are provided in DataTables, 
and which one is used is selected by the initialisation parameter:

$.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses - used when bJQueryUI is false
$.fn.dataTableExt.oJUIClasses - used when bJQueryUI is true
```

So in your case you would be doing

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.oJUIClasses.sSortColumn = "foobar"
```

Comment: I saw that in the docs and wasn't quite sure how to use it. Works like a charm. Thanks. I had to place the $.fn.dataTableExt... statement before my oTable definition.